# HTML pages loading problems and buffer

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I am using Django to create a Web App.

However, pages which rely heavily on jQuery Dialog and Forms take a long time to load (up to 20 seconds).

When the page loads, it buffers for a few seconds and then displays everything on the page on top of each other. To prevent users seeing this, I wanted to add a loading buffer to hide everything until the page loads.

I added this to the body

```
<div class="loader">
</div>
<div id="body" style="display:none;">
```

and this in the `document.ready`:

```
$('#body').show();
```

However, when this runs the page buffers for a few seconds - displays nothing - and then the loader appears for a very short period (>3 seconds) and then the page loads fully.

I don't understand why the loader does not display for the whole loading phase?

Comment: you should use `load` function to show loading then hide it when `document` is ready and show body.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but since the loading isn't hidden at start it should show since the begin of the load no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loader doesn't work like that. You have to do something like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery("#loaderInner").fadeOut(); 
    jQuery("#loader").delay(200).fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

When you place a buffer loader in html code like this:

```
<div id="loader">
  <div id="loaderInner">
    <div class="someLoader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your way and got the same result, page is loading full blank for about 10 seconds, then display the loading for barely two seconds and then the page is fully loaded

Comment: So the buffer loader is fine and something else is wrong. You can Inspect elements in your page, check the timeline and see what is taking so long.

Comment: I tried to use the dev console from mozilla to see in network what was load but i don't much information and i don't understand some of it, like it says the total load time was 13.23seconds, with 9.07 seconds of DomContent loading time and 9.31 seconds of Load time, how is that possible ?

Comment: That's a bit high for load time. This might help:https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/decrease-webpage-load-times/

Comment: Yeah i tried the usual test site, they can't even test it because it take 20+ seconds to load for them and cancel the test